# Can't retrieve any documents from MongoDB using NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Not sure why I am not getting any results from a GET call I am making with Postman.

Here is my server.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();

const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://[REDACTED]:[REDACTED]@cluster0.d5zbb.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

async function connect() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(uri);
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
connect();

const userRouter = require("./routes/users");
app.use("/users", userRouter);

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 8000");
});
```

Here is my models/Users.js:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  phoneNumber: String,
  isVendor: Boolean,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema, "users");
```

And here is my users.js route:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find({});
    console.log(users);
    res.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

In MongoDB, I have a `users` collection under a database and here is sample data:

```json
{"_id":{"$oid":"63f90e2c00f411064f0415a8"},"firstName":"John","lastName":"Customer","phoneNumber":"1111111111","isVendor":false}
```

The endpoint I am hitting is `http://localhost:8000/users` but it always console logs an empty array. Literally any kind of help is truly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't mix `async` / `try..catch` with the callback version of `find()`. Use `const users = await User.find({}); console.log(users); res.json(users);`. In your `catch` you're also failing to send a response. Add `res.sendStatus(500)`

Comment: Understood. I've changed it to this now but still no luck `router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find({});
    console.log(users);
    res.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});`

Comment: If it's still showing an empty array then it seems pretty clear that you have no documents in the `users` collection in the database you're connecting to

Answer (score 0):

Your folder naming and import are mismatched for the model.

Also, you have to specify your database name and then the collection name while connecting to MongoDB.
connection string: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/your_database_name";

Apart from this everything is fine with this code.

Documentation Link:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Can you go more into detail about the folder naming and import being mismatched? I don't quite understand

Comment: Here you are creating as models/Users.js but 
when importing in routes/users you are writing it as
[ const User = require("../models/User"); ]

you are writing (user) in this line of code but it should've been (users)

Answer (score -1):

After suffering through debugging MongoDB, I needed to specify the database name in the Mongo uri string. Here is the post that helped me: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-create-a-test-database/211636/2

Comment: Make sure to always include the end result in your answer, so anyone that might find your question useful can easily find how to solve it! [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).